# C# - dbf External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro, dbf, dbase

I am struggling here. I am trying to fetch data from dbf file. for that using the below connection string and code.

```
DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable();
        const string path = "D:\\Sample\\Database\\client.dbf";
        string conStr = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = \"dBase IV\"", Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        var connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        connection.Open();

        var command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select id from {0}", Path.GetFileName(path)), connection);

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var str = (string)reader["id"];
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
```

Few dbf file can be read and most of the dbf file cannot fetch. While execute the code ann error has been occured that **"External table is not in the expected format."**

Even though i am using different of connextion string like vfopledb, vfoledb1, jet, ace etc..

my machine is 64bit and i am using vs2013. Please help me.

*don't put negative because i have tried all stack over flow answer regarding this same issue.*

Comment: Have you tried using the name of the table in your select statement like `select id from client`? Do you get the same error? Which line is causing the error?

Comment: yes, i have tried that query also. but no improvement. same error will be there.

 While execute reader statement the error will comes.

Answer (score 4):

Use VFPOLEDB driver. Jet or ACE driver wouldn't recognize all dbf tables. VFPOLEDB driver is 32 bits, that means you should be targeting x86 in your C# project (properties/build target platform).

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable YourResultSet = new DataTable();
    string path = @"D:\Sample\Database\client.dbf";

    using (OleDbConnection connection =
    new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(
    string.Format("select id from {0}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)), connection))
    {
    connection.Open();
    YourResultSet.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
    connection.Close();
    }

    Form f = new Form();
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=YourResultSet};
    f.Controls.Add(dgv);
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your valuable answer. i have tried with your sample code and i have set the targeting CPU version as x86. but the error is **d:\sample\database\client.dbf is not a table.**.  Please help me

Comment: For it to work, the .dbf should be an xBase table in a format known to VFP. Maybe it is not or header might be corrupt. You can email the file to me so I can check if you wish (cetin dot basoz at deu dot edu dot tr)

Comment: And BTW, if it is a DBF known to VFP, you might repair it using the code (VFP code) on http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~NotATable~WIN_COM_API.